# Running Kafka Connect in distributed mode, no obvious errors, but data does not end up in sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Running Kafka Connect via this repo https://github.com/entechlog/kafka-examples/tree/master/kafka-connect-standalone except I have added extra configs for AWS MSK IAM authentication. I've also updated the .env file to use different variables, like the AWS MSK IAM jar file, AWS key/secret key credentials, and a few other minor things. Note that this repo runs in standalone mode, but I have updated the launch shell script to run in distributed mode: `exec connect-distributed /etc/"${COMPONENT}"/"${COMPONENT}".properties`. But I have NOT created a file called `kafka-connect.properties.template` because when I do, I get a whole host of errors like `Missing required configuration "group.id" which has no default value.` which makes no sense to me as I can see it in the docker-compose.yml file.

My goal is to get data from a third party Kafka cluster into BigQuery.

When I run my docker-compose file, I see no errors, a few warnings, but nothing that stands out to me. I get a lot of warnings like this: `[2021-12-14 01:57:37,917] WARN The configuration 'camelcase.default.dataset' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:380)`, and this dataset is required to send data to BigQuery. Not making sense why things like dataset are not being used.
Here are the latest logs:

```html
[2021-12-14 01:57:37,921] INFO Kafka version: 6.2.1-ce (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)

[2021-12-14 01:57:37,922] INFO Kafka commitId: 14770bfc4e973178 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:120)

[2021-12-14 01:57:37,922] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1639447057921 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:121)

[2021-12-14 01:57:39,332] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-3] Cluster ID: k2eIXxm_RkmWu2-R2d0N1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:279)

[2021-12-14 01:57:39,413] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-kafka-connect-group-3, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Cluster ID: k2eIXxm_RkmWu2-R2d0N1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:279)

[2021-12-14 01:57:39,428] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-kafka-connect-group-3, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Subscribed to partition(s): connect-configs-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer:1123)

[2021-12-14 01:57:39,428] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-kafka-connect-group-3, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition connect-configs-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState:619)

[2021-12-14 01:57:40,727] INFO Finished reading KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-configs (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:228)

[2021-12-14 01:57:40,728] INFO Started KafkaBasedLog for topic connect-configs (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:230)

[2021-12-14 01:57:40,729] INFO Started KafkaConfigBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore:290)

[2021-12-14 01:57:40,729] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Herder started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:312)

[2021-12-14 01:57:45,059] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Cluster ID: k2eIXxm_RkmWu2-R2d0N1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:279)

[2021-12-14 01:57:45,089] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Discovered group coordinator <bootstrap server and port here> (id: 2147483643 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:848)

[2021-12-14 01:57:45,095] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:221)

[2021-12-14 01:57:45,095] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:538)

[2021-12-14 01:57:45,957] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:538)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,038] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=1, memberId='connect-1-a4cc5355-60da-46c3-8228-bff2de664f2c', protocol='sessioned'} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:594)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,160] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=1, memberId='connect-1-a4cc5355-60da-46c3-8228-bff2de664f2c', protocol='sessioned'} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:758)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,161] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Joined group at generation 1 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-a4cc5355-60da-46c3-8228-bff2de664f2c', leaderUrl='http://kafka-connect:8083/', offset=10, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1694)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,162] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Catching up to assignment's config offset. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1119)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,162] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 10, reading to end of config log (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1183)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,359] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: 10 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1190)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,359] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 10 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1244)

[2021-12-14 01:57:49,359] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1272)

[2021-12-14 01:57:50,791] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-kafka-connect-group] Session key updated (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1582)
```

And also this:

```
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource will be ignored. 

WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource will be ignored. 

WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.

WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.

WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
```

And when I navigate to `http://localhost:8083/connectors` in my browser, I get an empty list `[]`.

Comment: You need to make an HTTP POST request to actual start the sink connector

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you!

Comment: How to make it, I am trying https://github.com/dmathieu/kafka-connect-opensearch this connector. could you please help me.

Comment: @ManojSharma better to post your own question and show what you've done and where you're stuck. Then we can help.

Comment: @SultanofSwing I have asked separately. Can you see and reply there.